# Synonymous idiom for "more x than you can shake a stick at"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

It's very difficult to search the web for synonymous idioms, at least for me. I found [Origin of "More X than you can shake a stick at"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92393/origin-of-more-x-than-you-can-shake-a-stick-at), but I'm really trying to find a similar phrase to it.

> We have an overabundance of *noun*.

The only thing I could think of was "we got stacks on stacks", but that's not appropriate for many situations.

Comment: I've always liked "We have [noun] coming out of our ears." personally.

Comment: Oh, yeah, didn't think of that! Or "We're in [noun] up to our eyeballs"

Comment: Unrelated, but I worked at a gas station and an old man asked me if we had non-filter cigs. I said "we have more than you can shake a stick at". He said "I got a pretty big stick" and grabbed his crotch. Was funny

Comment: I'm partial to "we've got [noun] for days"

Comment: I always liked "shit-ton"

Comment: "We're in up to our eyeballs" doesn't mean that. It doesn't mean an overabundance of an item, it specifically refers to workload.

Comment: I'm not proud of myself for this one, but "buttloads" is the first thing that came to mind. I'd stick with the "cornucopia" answer below.

Comment: There are more ways to say this that there are definitions of "Bad" in the dictionary.  Largely because this is one of those expressive-meanings that is so common, that creative and/or ambitious speakers and writers feel free (or even compelled) to come up with their own idioms.  You may want to try your own hand at it...

Comment: I can't bring myself to make an entire answer just for my tiny addition. Try "enough foo to stop a train". Honestly though you should be using "a shit-ton" as prev. suggested :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ***We're swimming in*** [noun]

Also, if you wanted to express that you have so much of something that it's causing an issue, you could say:

> *We're **[up to our ears/eyeballs/chin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+up+to+eyeballs+in)** in [noun]*

or

> ***We can't move for*** [noun]

Here's an example of the last expression's use in literature:

> *Chimera teems with leather driving gloves and woolly jumpers. **We can't move for** all the socks and scarves. They drift here in their thousands.*

<sub>Gomm, P. (2014) *Chimera*</sub>

Comment: A lot of great answers here, and I appreciate all! I'm giving this the checkmark because it fits in the context from which the question arose. Some of the answers might better fit someone else who stumbles upon this question in the future.

Answer (score 13):

There are truckloads of answers to this question: s--tloads. I bet you can find tons if you look around. You can't throw a stone without hitting one. They are a dime a dozen, really.

Comment: I almost downvoted this answer for not answering the question. lol. Too clever for me.

Comment: Important question: which is more stuff, a shitload or an asston? https://stronglang.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/units-of-fucking-measure/ (link contains many variants, mostly cussy)

Answer (score 11):

Two similar idiomatic phrases come to mind:

1. from here to the moon;
2. enough X to choke a horse (or choke something else large, with a big mouth).

Examples from the wild:

> Baker and gang are searching for any excuse to blame Israel for world-wide Muslim Terror and particularly in Iraq. Baker is willing to chew noxious bubble-gum and stretch it **from here to the moon** in his effort to convert terror in Iraq over to Israel.

(From *THINK-ISRAEL BLOG-EDS*, ["Happy New Year"](http://www.think-israel.org/dec06bloged.html).)

> **enough to choke a horse**
>   A huge or excessive amount. *When my grandmother cooks for family gatherings, she always makes enough to choke a horse!*

[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. S.v. "enough to choke a horse." Retrieved February 3 2016 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/enough+to+choke+a+horse ]

A common variant of the 'choke a horse' is

> **enough to sink a ship**
>   Also, **enough to sink a battleship**. A more than sufficient amount, as in *They brought enough food to sink a ship.* [; mid-1900s ]

[enough to sink a ship. Dictionary.com. The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Houghton Mifflin Company. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enough to sink a ship (accessed: February 03, 2016).]

If whatever it is you have a lot of is distasteful in some way, another variant phrase is

> **enough to gag a maggot**
>   *adverb phrase*
>   Very disgusting; repulsive : *His excuse was enough to gag a maggot.* / *"Oh, gross," Lou Ann said. "Gag a maggot!"* (1970s+)

[enough to gag a maggot. Dictionary.com. The Dictionary of American Slang. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enough to gag a maggot (accessed: February 03, 2016).]

Comment: +1. Also, I found [enough to sink a ship](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/enough+to+sink+a+ship)! You can add it to your answer if you want.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy, thanks, I was about to--same source as gag a maggot.

Comment: Interestingly enough I'd always thought mine was more of a British idiom, but according to the free dictionary it's American. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/coming+out+of+ears

Comment: Regarding "enough to gag a maggot" I'd argue that this one is using enough more as a synonym for "sufficient" rather than denoting having a large quantity of something.

Answer (score 9):

Consider,

*We have more [noun] than we know what to do with*

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22than+we+know+what+to+do+with%22&biw=707&bih=464&prmd=nvi&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMkd3gr9vKAhXCWBQKHUHTC-AQ_AUICygG)

*We have [noun] to burn*

> have something to burn: *Fig.* to have lots of something, such as money, power, food, space, cars, etc.; to have more of something than one needs. *Look at the way Tom buys things*. *You'd think he had money to burn*. *If I had all that acting talent to burn as he does*, *I'd have won an Oscar by now*. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+to+burn)

*We have [an embarrassment of riches](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=embarrassment+of+riches%2Cembarras+de+richesses%2Cembarras+de+richesse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cembarrassment%20of%20riches%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20richesses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cembarras%20de%20richesse%3B%2Cc0) of [noun]*

> [*An embarrassment of riches*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22have+an+embarrassment+of+riches+of%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9j_-Pi9zKAhUC8j4KHXdtCSMQ_AUIBygA&biw=599&bih=393&dpr=2) is an idiom that means an overabundance of something, or too much of a good thing, that originated in 1738 as John Ozell's translation of a French play, [*L'Embarras des richesses*](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2013/07/embarrassment-of-riches-l-des-richesses.html) (1726), by Léonor Jean Christine Soulas d'Allainval. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassment_of_riches)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps:

> We have [noun] **coming out of our ears**.

From [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/coming+out+of+ears):

> **coming out of one's ears** *Fig.* very numerous or abundant. (As if people or things were coming in great numbers from many sources including unlikely ones.) *I've got phone and e-mail messages coming out of my ears. We are very busy at the factory. We have orders coming out of our ears.*

Comment: "Coming out of..." um... other places is common also.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Not always the implied bodily orifices either.  "The wazoo", "the woodwork", and "the tapestries" are common sources for things that come out in abundance.  (Okay, the "wazoo" *could* be a bodily orifice, it's not clearly defined...)

Comment: I daresay [eTrade defined wazoo for us](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0_tfoTTGOQ) ;)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe try:

> I'm **up to my neck in** x

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+neck) lists it as:

> ***up to one's neck** (in something) and ***up to one's ears*** (in something); ***up to one's eyeballs*** (in something)
>
> having a lot of something;
>
> Fig. very much involved in something; immersed in something

Comment: Also "up to my eyeballs..." and more rarely "up to my ears..."

Answer (score 4):

Similar to, but distinct from the original example:

> You can't swing a stick around here without knocking over a couple of
>   *nouns.*

Comment: +1, you can swing other things. First thing I thought of was "[can't swing a dead cat without hitting a {thing}](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Can%27t+swing+a+dead+cat.&defid=2035269)".

Answer (score 3):

Among the other great suggestions, I'll add:

> We have a **cornucopia** full of X.

From the second definition at [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cornucopia): a great amount or source of something.

Comment: How regal of you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try the phrase *to have [something] in spades*.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_spades

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+spades

Answer (score 2):

Common on the west coast of Canada: "out the ying yang," which www.yourdictionary.com defines as "Adverb. (comparative more out the ying yang, superlative most out the ying yang) . In abundance; in much greater quantity than is necessary or than is desired."  An accurate definition but a superlative for superabundant seems superfluous.

Comment: I *know* I've heard this on a commercial or something, but I don't remember which one or where.